# The spring-stream sends a message with "text/plain" content-type instead of "application/json"

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I would like to generate responses on my queue with content type application/json because payload contains the json object.

But...

Don't know why my spring-stream (based on RabbitMQ) always generates the message with below headers (payload is correct and has JSON form).

```
(view from rabbit ui)
properties:
    delivery_mode:  2
    headers:    
      contentType:  text/plain
      originalContentType:  application/json;charset=UTF-8
    content_type:   text/plain
```

So the content_type equals to **text/plain** instead of **application/json;charset=UTF-8**.

I have tried to set **content-type** in configurations like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        content-type: application/json
      bindings:
        my-channel:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: my-channel-rs
          producer:
            exchange-type: direct
            max-length: 1000
```

but did not help.

I have the feeling that in correct response the single header content-type should exist with value "application/json".

But maybe I am wrong? Is anybody able to explain above behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using 1.3 version of S-C-Stream. Could you please confirm? We can certainly take a look.
Also, FWIW, the whole 'originalContentType' issue is not a problem as long as you have a consumer that is SCSt application (as it's going to be reset to what you expect), but I am assuming that it is not, correct?

Also, any chance you can upgrade to 2.0.0.M3. There has been a lot of improvements around `contentType` resolution.

Comment: `originalContentType:  application/json;charset=UTF-8` - the rabbit binder is not intended for communication with arbitrary rabbitmq applications. Use the `rabbit` sink for that purpose.

Comment: 1. Yes it is the 1st case when my consumer does not base on a s-c-stream :) It is totally different technology, developed by someone else.

2. Version of spring-cloud-stream is `Chelsea.SR2` (`spring cloud dependencies = Dalston.SR4`).

3. Upgrade to 2.0.0.M3?
Application works on production. I would like rather wait for official release of spring boot 2 with spring cloud attached.

Comment: @GaryRussell you say that I can't use spring-cloud-stream as a producer of messages for consumers which don't base on spring-cloud-stream? What do you mean by "Rabbit Sink"?

Comment: Yes; that is what I am saying (at least until 2.0). The [rabbit sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/rabbit) is a spring-cloud-stream app that receives messages from (any) Spring Cloud Stream binder and publishes messages to rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I needed the underlying spring-amqp to use the "content-type" header to set the actual content type. Spring-amqp figures it out by inspecting the class of the message payload regardless of the "content-type" header.

I created a pull request that may or may not be accepted: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/763/commits/25e4f9adf523a802ac5f26dd373eff8bb764fb49